# Recieve alert on any specific windows service entered into stopped state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want email notification if any specific EC2 windows service entered into the stopped state.

I configured CloudWatch, able to receive logs of all windows services.
Created a lambda function to get notify when any service entered into the stopped state, but the problem is I am receiving alert only when I click on the test function.

I am receiving CloudWatch logs like this:

```
03:43:02 [System] [INFORMATION] [7036] [Service Control Manager] [mydomain.com] [The Background Intelligent Transfer Service service entered the running state.]
03:43:02 [System] [INFORMATION] [7040] [Service Control Manager] [mydomain.com] [The start type of the Background Intelligent Transfer Service service was changed from demand start to auto start.]
03:43:02 [System] [INFORMATION] [7036] [Service Control Manager] [mydomain.com] [The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service service entered the running state.]
03:45:02 [System] [INFORMATION] [7040] [Service Control Manager] [mydomain.com] [The start type of the Background Intelligent Transfer Service service was changed from auto start to demand start.]
```

This is my lambda function:

```
import boto3
import time

client = boto3.client('logs')
sns = boto3.client('sns')
instance_name = "Development"
a1 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   response = client.get_log_events(
   logGroupName = 'Eadev',
   logStreamName = 'i-01fe1z56y790cq',
   startTime = a1,
   startFromHead = False
 )

event01 = '[System] [INFORMATION] [7036] [Service Control Manager] [mydomain.com] [The DebtManager-Host service entered the stopped state.]'
event02 = '[System] [INFORMATION] [7036] [Service Control Manager] [mydomain.com] [The DebtManager-Controller service entered the stopped state.]'

for i in response['events']:
   if event01 == i['message']:
   print(event01)
   sns.publish( TargetArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:3913948:testsns",Message = instance_name +"  "+ event01)

   if event02 == i['message']:
   print(event02)
   sns.publish( TargetArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:3913948:testsns",Message = instance_name +" "+ event02)
```

I expected email notification from any service stopped, but I am receiving alert only when I clicked on test in Lambda function.

Comment: Do you have any Triggers configured for your Lambda function? That is, what causes it to activate (aside from clicking Test)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i tried to set up a trigger from cloudwatch rule, but somehow i am confused how to set there, could you please suggest me how can i configure that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your desired situation is:

- The **Amazon CloudWatch agent** on the Windows instance sends log data to Amazon CloudWatch Logs
- **Send a notification** when a particular entry is detected in the log file

Rather than triggering a Lambda function for *every log message*, you can **use CloudWatch Logs Filter Metrics to trigger a CloudWatch Alarm**:

- [Collecting Metrics and Logs from Amazon EC2 Instances and On-Premises Servers with the CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html)
- [Searching and Filtering Log Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) to detect the desired messages by [Creating Metric Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringPolicyExamples.html)
- This pushes metrics into **Amazon CloudWatch Metrics**
- You can then create a traditional **Amazon CloudWatch Alarm** on the metric and have it trigger when a certain number of such messages are received
- A CloudWatch Alarm can send a notification an **Amazon SNS topic**

For an end-to-end example, see: [Use Amazon CloudWatch Logs Metric Filters to Send Alerts - The IT Hollow](https://theithollow.com/2017/12/11/use-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-metric-filters-send-alerts/)

Alternatively, you can use an **AWS Lambda function**:

- [Collect Metrics and Logs from Amazon EC2 Instances and On-Premises Servers with the CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html)
- Use [Real-time Processing of Log Data with Subscriptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html)
- It can accept a **subscription filter** to identify the records of interest
- It can then **trigger an AWS Lambda function**, which you can program to do whatever you wish (eg send a message to an Amazon SNS topic)